# Clustering in Torch

Tags: lua, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, torch

I am trying to learn the [Torch](http://torch.ch/) library for machine learning.

I know that the focus of Torch is neural networks, but just for the sake of it I was trying to run kmeans on it. If nothing, Torch implements fast contiguous storage which should be analogous to numpy arrays, and the [Torch cheatsheet](https://github.com/torch/torch7/wiki/Cheatsheet) cites the [unsup](https://github.com/koraykv/unsup) library for unsupervised learning, so why not?

I already have [a benchmark](https://github.com/andreaferretti/kmeans) that I use for K-means implementations. Even though all the implementations there are intentionally using an unoptimized algorithm (the README explains why), LuaJIT is able to cluster 100000 points in 611ms. An optimized (or shall I say, not intentionally slowed down) implementation in Nim (not on the repository) runs in 68 ms,so I was expecting something in-between.

Unfortunately, things are much worse, so I suspect I am doing something awfully wrong. What I have written is

```
require 'io'
cjson = require 'cjson'
require 'torch'
require 'unsup'

content = io.open("points.json"):read("*a")
data = cjson.decode(content)
points = torch.Tensor(data)
timer = torch.Timer()
centroids, counts = unsup.kmeans(points, 10, 15)

print(string.format('Time required: %f s', timer:time().real))
```

and the running time is around 6 seconds!

Can anyone check if I have done something wrong in using Torch/unsup?

If anyone wants to try it, the file `points.json` is in the above repository

Comment: *running time is around 6 seconds*: what about your hardware/software?

Comment: It is a Vaio laptop, but anyway I get 611 ms for a very naive implementation in pure lua on the same computer

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone check if I have done something wrong in using Torch/unsup?

Everything sounds correct (note: using `local` variables is recommended):

- `data` is a 2-dimensional table and you use the corresponding [Torch constructor](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/3585ab5/doc/tensor.md#torchtensortable),
- `points` is a 2-dimensional tensor with nb. rows = nb. of points and nb. cols = points dimension (2 here). This is what `unsup.kmeans` [expects as input](https://github.com/koraykv/unsup/blob/605f777/kmeans.lua#L4).

What you can do is change the batch size (4th argument). It may impact the performance. You can also use the verbose mode that will output the average time per iteration:

```
-- batch size = 5000, no callback, verbose mode
centroids, counts = unsup.kmeans(points, 10, 15, 5000, nil, true)
```

Comment: If this is the case, it sounds worrying. An [unoptimized implementation](https://github.com/andreaferretti/kmeans/blob/master/lua/kmeans.lua) using pure Lua tables runs in 1/10th the time. I will try changing the batch size tomorrow at work, but it seems unsup is doing something wrong

Comment: That's indeed a huge difference. I believe speed was not the initial focus. Some loops might optimized like [this one](https://github.com/koraykv/unsup/blob/605f777/kmeans.lua#L70-L73) (by replacing it with a single matrix-matrix multiplication) or [this one](https://github.com/koraykv/unsup/blob/605f777/kmeans.lua#L79-L81) (by directly manipulating the [raw data](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#result-datatensor-asnumber)).

Comment: @Andrea any update on whether unsup is still/overall slower than an implementation in Lua?

Comment: @RaziShaban It seems it is doing a different thing. See the discussion in this issue: https://github.com/koraykv/unsup/issues/27